# Why colon is used in below line of code, i am not able to understand its significance :-

Tags: angularjs

```
<nav class="navbar`enter code here`-inverse" ng-class="::{'navbar':!isViewNative, 'is-native': isViewNative}" role="navigation">
```

could someone please explain me, i have just started learning angular java script.

Answer (score 2):

angular has Digest Cycle And Dirty Check process in background. when you use :: the expression will stop recalculating after the first digest, its generally used for *"one time"* binding.